# Убрать при первом открытии сайта все вспывающие окна, соглашения, cookies окна и т.д. автоматически

Tags: python, html, веб-программирование, cookie, браузер

Какими инструментами, способами, можно автоматически закрывать, соглашаться, с всплывающими окнами чтобы

1. автоматический соглашаться
2. Если нет такой опции, то закрыть окно [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вангую, что речь идет о парсинге через selenium. Или ошибся?

Comment: можно через селениум, можно и другими способами

Comment: Я не очень понял. Вам то как нужно? Если речь идет об обычном ежедневном вебсерфинге, то рекомендую аддон `Ublock origin` он есть практически для любого браузера

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно в настройках браузера отключить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]